# Git not appearing in NetBeans context menu

Tags: git, svn, netbeans

I am working on a NetBeans project that is being managed with Git. One of the packages we are using was created in another project that used SVN, so in the folder that contains the sources there was a hidden .svn directory.

The problem is that, unlike with other packages, the Git submenu does not appear in the context menu of this package. A Subversion submenu appears instead, even if I delete the .svn folder. Furthermore, if I restart NetBeans the .svn folder appears again.

Whenever I do some action with Git, this package is ignored. How can I tell NetBeans that this package is a Git folder too? I can't even stage it from the console. That is ignored as well.

Comment: I ended up just changing the name of the package, and it works properly now. This, however, might not be always an option, so a solution would still be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility which could explain why the SVN menu was still present, even after removing the .svn, is the cache:

```
~/.netbeans/6.8/var/cache/svncache
```

That cache is already mentioned in several bugs like [bug 153072](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=153072).

Comment: I am using version 7.2.1 of NetBeans and this cache folder does not seem to exist anymore, so it looks like someone else is the culprit.

Comment: @broncoAbierto replace 6.8 by any version you are using, and that cache should exist (it simply might have removed after your package renaming)

Comment: Yeah, I searched the 7.2.1 folder, but I didn't find that cache directory! ls -A yields this: .  ..  filehistory  imported  log

Comment: @broncoAbierto I suspect that cache has been cleaned after you got rid of svn by renaming your package.

Comment: That's possible, since I didn't look for it before renaming the package.